# What is the standard conform syntax for template constructor inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, using-statement

GCC 4.8.1 accepts

```
template <typename T>
class Subclass : public Baseclass<T>
{
public:
    using typename Baseclass<T>::Baseclass;
};
```

but MSVC does not. On the other hand, MSVC accepts

```
template <typename T>
class Subclass : public Baseclass<T>
{
public:
    using typename Baseclass::Baseclass;
};
```

but GCC does not. Then I've seen another kind of declaration in this questions: [c++11 inheriting template constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760522/c11-inheriting-template-constructors)

```
template <typename T>
class Subclass : public Baseclass<T>
{
public:
    using typename Baseclass::Baseclass<T>;
};
```

for which MSVC warns about an "obsolete declaration style" and GCC says

```
prog.cpp:8:24: error: ‘template<class T> class Baseclass’ used without template parameters
        using typename Baseclass::Baseclass<T>;
```

I thought the first example would be the standard conform syntax. Intuitively, it looks right to me.

What is the c++11 standard conform syntax?

Comment: What MSVC version? VS2013 does not support inheriting constructors. AFAIK, the first one is the correct syntax. `using Baseclass::BaseClass<T>` should work for cases where `BaseClass` itself is not a class template, but has a constructor template.

Comment: @Praetorian Now that is surprising. But I only ever used the default and copy constructor, and now after testing a different constructor, I see you are right. Are copy and default constructors inherited automatically?

Comment: You'll have to check the standard, but I'm pretty sure the special member functions are *never* inherited. They may be automatically declared by the compiler in the derived class following the usual rules for their generation.

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement), all constructors should be inherited. So even something like `Base::Base(int value)`. Edit: And GCC does it: http://ideone.com/J0ToW2

Comment: Huh? Why is there a `Baseclass` and a `BaseClass`?

Comment: Yes, of course `Base::Base(int)` will be inherited, but that's neither a default nor a copy constructor. See [class.inhctor]/3 which states that default and copy/move constructors are left out from the candidate set of inherited constructors.

Comment: Since members of dependent base classes are not searched for in non-depended contexts, I think you have to provide the template argument for the `BaseClass` before the `::`.

Comment: I am pretty sure the correct way to inherit constructors here is `using Baseclass<T>::Baseclass;`, no `typename`, and providing the template argument (at least) left of `::`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a bit buried in the standard. A using declaration is defined as (7.3.3):

```
using [typename] nested-name-specifier unqualified-id;
```

The `nested-name-specifier` resolves after some steps into `simple-template-id` which is defined as

```
template-name < [template-argument-list] >
```

In short, the standard conforming syntax is

```
template <typename T>
class Subclass : public Baseclass<T>
{
public:
    using typename Baseclass<T>::Baseclass;
};
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use `typename` here: you’re not after the injected-class-name of the base, but its constructors.