# How does the Standard allow inheriting constructors via a dependent typedef-name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Inheriting constructors has been around since C++11, but what I don't understand is how the standard allows a typedef-name to be used *as the dependent name* in a using-declaration.

This works (and I'm glad, it really simplifies some things), but I can't figure out how:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class foo
{
    T m_data = 0;

 public:
    explicit foo () = default;
    explicit foo (T &&idata): m_data (std::move(idata)) {}
    foo (foo<T> const &) = default;
    auto data() const noexcept { return m_data; }
};


template <class T>
class bar: public foo<T>
{
    typedef foo<T> base_type;
  public:
    using base_type::base_type; // this is good, but HUH?

    // error: out-of-line constructor for 'foo' cannot have template arguments
    //using foo<T>::foo<T>;  
};

int main()
{
    bar <int> b {3};
    return b.data();
}
```

I've tried it with several different compilers [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5KbhMEnrj) as well as MSVC in Visual Studio directly and it works every time.

I don't understand how the standard allows `base_type::base_type` to be recognized as a base class constructor when `base_type` is a typedef name.  `base_type` is the same as `foo<T>`, but `using foo<T>::foo<T>` is a syntax error.

Just to clarify: **I'm not asking** why `foo<T>::foo<T>` doesn't work.  I'm asking why `base_type::base_type` **does** work.

Comment: You can use the injected class name too, btw. It just has to be spelled out as  `bar::foo::foo`.

Comment: See [C++ using declaration with typename in inheriting-constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944000/c-using-declaration-with-typename-in-inheriting-constructors)

Comment: `typedef`s are not new types so `base_type::base_type` is the same as `foo<T>::foo<T>`

Comment: @RichardCritten  This isn't so much about _types_ as it is about _dependent names_ in a using declaration.

Comment: @JasonLiam  Nowhere in that thread do they use a typedef name as the dependent name,

Comment: `using foo<T>::foo<T>` simply should be `using foo<T>::foo;` instead.

Comment: You just used wrong syntax, it should be `using foo<T>::foo;`. I guess it doesn't matter for `typedef`/`using` type, since it can't be cut it in middle.

Comment: @sklott This is a simplified example.  We don't care why foo<T>::foo<T> doesn't work, we only care about why `base_type::base_type` does work.

Comment: @Klaus See my comment to sklott.

Comment: Are you looking for the standard's paragraph that allows this? Because the standard doesn't have to accomplish anything --- it merely defines behaviour. It could define impossible behaviour without any problem (it would be unimplementable, but it could be specified).

Comment: @bitmask It would have to define how `base_type` can be the dependent name.

Comment: As far as I understand, this was specifically added in C++11, I don't have link to standard, but you can take look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration in "Inheriting constructors" section. Also, `typedef` and `using` just creating alias for type, so it should work exactly same as original type everywhere it is used.

Comment: @sklott As stated in my very first sentence. When you see the `language-lawyer` tag, be prepared to get out a really good microscope to look at that pin and start counting angels.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I didn't understand what you are really asking at first. `using foo<T>::foo;` and `using base_type::foo;` are both standard compliant. But `using base_type::base_type;` may be not.

Comment: `base_type` is an alias to `foo<T>`. It is not a macro that just replaces it. So behaviour is different. The reason why `foo<T>::foo<T>` doesn't compile is just some syntax nuance. It might look misleading to compiler as if there are two templates. `base_type::base_type` simply doesn't have the same issue. Sometimes writing an alias is the proper way to call the right function. Say, `using T = std::string; str.~T();` while `str.~std::string` doesn't compile due to operator precedence.

Comment: @sklott Maybe I should remove "how" from the title, then.  (But I won't).

Answer (score 2):

[[class.qual]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.qual#1):

> In a lookup for a qualified name *N* whose lookup context is a class C in which function names are not ignored, [...]

> - if *N* is dependent and is the terminal name of a *using-declarator* that names a constructor,

> *N* is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.

[[namespace.udecl]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1):

> If the terminal name of the *using-declarator* is dependent, the *using-declarator* is considered to name a constructor if and only if the *nested-name-specifier* has a terminal name that is the same as the *unqualified-id*.

---

C++20 wording (pre-[P1787](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html)):

[[class.qual]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.qual#2):

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class C: [...]

> - in a *using-declarator* of a *using-declaration* that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is the same as the *identifier* or the *simple-template-id*'s *template-name* in the last component of the *nested-name-specifier*,

> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.

Comment: _simple-template-id's template-name_!!! Wow! Expect a green check mark in 24 hours or so.